# config is not defined ,deploying in heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to  deploy my django app on heroku ,I want to use remote postgre on heroku as well.
dj-database-url is defined in my requirement file which I have imported in setting.py as well .

```
requirements.txt

dj-database-url
gunicorn
Babel==2.6.0





settings.py

import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {

    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}
```

While deploying I have the below error ,anything I miss here ?

```
"NameError: name 'config' is not defined"



File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_b158ddc41a15ba9cab330674e51f4eff/restful01/settings.py", line 103, in <module>
           default=config('DATABASE_URL')
       NameError: name 'config' is not defined
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}`

Comment: its ok now ,I have another issue to to do migrations,

                                              psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...

Comment: deployment went further but I still have error . Traceback (most recent call last):
ute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co..

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Why should one "try" that?

Comment: Thanks guys,the update from Sergii help me fix ,for the above comment error,  I have raised another case to track it as it s a separated issue